# Custom logger is not being triggered when DEBUG=False

Tags: python, django, django-logging

I have the following piece of code in `settings.py`:

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': { '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue', },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'kodular': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'account.reporter.KodularExceptionHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'kodular'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'DEBUG'),
        },
    },
}
```

The `KodularExceptionHandler` class looks like this:

```py
from copy import copy
import json
import logging
import requests

from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.log import AdminEmailHandler
from django.views.debug import ExceptionReporter

class KodularExceptionHandler(AdminEmailHandler):
    def emit(self, record, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Triggered")
        try:
            request = record.request
            subject = record.getMessage()
        except Exception:
            return

        if record.exc_info:
            exc_info = record.exc_info
        else:
            exc_info = (None, record.getMessage(), None)

        reporter = ExceptionReporter(request, is_email=True, *exc_info)
        message = "%s\n\n%s" % (self.format(copy(record)), reporter.get_traceback_text())

        text = "**Error Level**: *%s* | **Status Code**: `%s`\n\n\n" % (record.levelname, record.status_code)

        url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/'+settings.GITHUB_ORG+'/'+settings.GITHUB_REPO+'/issues'
        session = requests.Session()
        session.auth = (settings.GITHUB_USERNAME, settings.GITHUB_PASSWORD)
        issue = {'title': subject,
                'body': text+message.replace('*', '\*').replace('_', '\_'),
                'labels': ["error"]}
        r = session.post(url, json.dumps(issue))
        if r.status_code != 201:
            return
        github_issue_url = json.loads(r.content)['html_url']



        if record.levelname == "WARNING":
            return

        attachments =  [{
            'title': subject,
            'color': 'danger',
            'actions': [{
                'type': 'button',
                'text': 'Github Issue',
                'url': github_issue_url,
                'style': 'primary',
            }],
            'fields': [{
                "title": "Level",
                "value": record.levelname,
                "short": True
            },{
                "title": "Method",
                "value": request.method if request else 'No Request',
                "short": True
            },{
                "title": "Path",
                "value": request.path if request else 'No Request',
                "short": True
            },{
                "title": "User",
                "value": ( (request.user.username + ' (' + str(request.user.pk) + ')'
                        if request.user.is_authenticated else 'Anonymous' )
                        if request else 'No Request' ),
                "short": True
            },{
                "title": "Status Code",
                "value": record.status_code,
                "short": True
            },{
                "title": "UA",
                "value": ( request.META['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
                        if request and request.META else 'No Request' ),
                "short": False
            },{
                "title": 'GET Params',
                "value": json.dumps(request.GET) if request else 'No Request',
                "short": False
            },{
                "title": "POST Data",
                "value": json.dumps(request.POST) if request else 'No Request',
                "short": False
            }]
        }]

        data = { 'payload': json.dumps({'attachments': attachments}) }
        webhook_url = settings.SLACK_HOOK
        r = requests.post(webhook_url, data=data)
```

---

When I set `DEBUG = True` in settings, everything works properly: console handles the error (and prints "Reached"), Github issue gets created and Slack notification is sent.

However, if I set `DEBUG = False`, things go wrong. As it's supposed to be, console outputs less information; but neither Github issue gets created or Slack notification is sent.

I think there is an issue somewhere on the logger handler. It looks like `KodularExceptionHandler` is not being triggered, as console doesn't print "Reached", whereas when debug is enabled it does.

**Any idea what can be causing the custom error reporting class of not being triggered when debug is set to false?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a little issue on my `urls.py` file. I am using custom error pages handlers:

```py
from account import views

handler404 = views.error404
handler500 = views.error500
```

However, the file `views.py` looks like this:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from account.admin import requires_login

def error404(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'error/404.html')

def error500(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'error/500.html')
```

I fixed everything by changing it to

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

from account.admin import requires_login

def error404(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'error/404.html', status=404)

def error500(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'error/500.html', status=500)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because this is the default behaviour (as defined in the config) of the `AdminEmailHandler`, which is the parent class of your `KodularExceptionHandler` class. Since the `AdminEmailHandler` class has the `django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse` filter enabled when the django app is loading (https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/utils/log.py#L49), this filter extends to any classes inheriting from the handler.

You can either use the setting `'disable_existing_loggers': True`, or not inherit from `AdminEmailHandler` at all. If you look at the code of `AdminEmailHandler` (https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/utils/log.py#L79), you will note that you have overridden most of its code (except the `__init__`). Maybe you can inherit from `logging.Handler` instead.

Comment: I know, but the problem is that it's working in the other way. It works only when DEBUG=True

Comment: @DiegoBarreiro you're contradicting yourself. In your question you say it works when DEBUG=False: "When I set DEBUG = False in settings, everything works properly"

Comment: @dirkgroten Yeah, sorry, I realized now... I messed the question, I have edited it now. I was able to fix the issue, there was an issue with my custom views; I'll write now the answer.